# Frida, hook OKHttp Library does not work with examples

Tags: frida

I'm trying to hook functions of the OKHttp library by using then following Frida script:

---

```
setTimeout(function(){
    Java.perform(function (){
        console.log("-- Hook OKHttp library --");

        try {
            var Builder = Java.use('okhttp3.CertificatePinner$Builder');
            var Pin = Java.use('okhttp3.CertificatePinner$Pin');
            var OkHttpClient = Java.use('okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder');
            console.log("OkHTTP classes found");


            Builder.add.overload.implementation = function(a, b) {
                console.log("TEST ADD");
            }

            Pin.matches.overload.implementation = function (a) {
                console.log("TEST matches")
                return true;
            }

            OkHttpClient.certificatePinner.overload.implementation = function (a) {
                console.log("TEST certificatePinner");
            }

            console.log("OkHTTP functions found");            
        } catch (err) {
            // If we dont have a ClassNotFoundException exception, raise the
            // problem encountered.
            console.log("OkHTTP 3.x classes/functions not Found");
        }

    });
},0);
```

---

And I am executing the following code in my Android application:

---

```
            CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
                    .add(certificateDNWildcard, certificateHash)
                    .build();
            //Create http client with pinned certificate
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .certificatePinner(certificatePinner)
                    .build();
```

---

As you can see I am calling the function `.add(certificateDNWildcard, certificateHash)` which I am trying to hook. However, nothing is printed in the terminal when I execute this function. Furthermore, the output of my terminal is:

```
-- Hook OKHttp library --
OkHTTP classes found
OkHTTP functions found
```

Hence, it does find the classes and functions; however, the hook itself does not work effectively. Could someone help me?

I am using:

```
* Frida 12.8.11
* Android 10
* ARM64
```

Comment: The common way to bypass pinning is not to hook the Builder classes (as there are often multiple ways how to build an instance). Instead hook the resulting class and the method where the pinning is performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either:

```js
// works if add method has a single implementation
Builder.add.implementation = function(a, b) {
    console.log("TEST ADD");
}
```

or

```js
// always works
Builder.add.overload('java.lang.String', 'java.lang.String').implementation = function(a, b) {
    console.log("TEST ADD");
}
```